# Disable Oracle Linux Network registration on a cloned virtual machine

Tags: linux

I have a virtual machine running Oracle Linux 6.5 that I have cloned from a production VM.  The original machine was registered to the Oracle Linux Network, but I'd like the cloned VM to just pull packages from the public Oracle and EPEL repos.   How can I disable the registration on the clone without unregistering from OLN, which would also ungregister the production machine?

Answer (score 0):

I've not used 6.5 but I hope this will be valid for this version as well.

Each server is identified by its UUID. When you clone a system, you need to change its UUID in the config file for ULN.

Start by running `uuidgen` to get a new UUID:

```
# /usr/bin/uuidgen -r
1c460880-5a10-4d19-a115-5d5d409ace39
```

Then edit the file `/etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date-uuid` and replace the `rhnuuid` value with the string you just created:

```
# vi /etc/sysconfig/rhn/up2date-uuid
uuid[comment]=Universally Unique ID for this server
#rhnuuid=91d0junk-1538-11db-8f59-123bdba2bb0f
rhnuuid=1c460880-5a10-4d19-a115-5d5d409ace39
```

Then re-run the `up2date` utility

Comment: Thanks for your answer, @Jenny D. Oracle Linux 6.5 does not seem to use up2date any longer.   The up2date command and up2date-uuid files do not exist.  I did find the Oracle registration information in /etc/sysconfig/rhn/systemid.    I've renamed this file temporarily to see if yum would still find the public repositories (they still exist in /etc/yum.repos.d), but no joy there.   I'm now researching what replaced the up2date-uuid file in Oracle/RedHat/CentOs 6.